# Is it possible to workaround the maxlist setting in proftp?

Tags: ftp, python, git

I help admin a website which runs on a shared host. The host uses ProFTP and is using the maxlist directive to limit the number of items returned in a directory listing. One other thing to note is that I don't have shell access to the server.

I'm currently attempting to place the entire site under version control (git). The server doesn't have this installed so I've decided that I'll pull the site onto a local server, put that under git and write a script that will use FTP to upload new versions of files.

The method I've decided to use to pull the site is to create a python script which uses the ftplib module to connect and transfer all files. I've tested it on a small scale and it works quite well, but unfortunately there are directories on the main site which have more than *maxlist* files, so as it stands my script won't be able to get the entire site. Does anyone know if there is any way to workaround the -maxlist- setting, or if there are other methods I can use to achieve what I need?

Answer (score 0):

You could try fetching the list of all files starting with `a`, then `b` and so on.